# Difference between Kernel, Kernel-Thread and User-Thread

Tags: linux, kernel

i'm not sure, if i totally understand the above mentioned differences, so i'd like to explain it on my own and you can interrupt me, as far as i get wrong:
"A kernel is the initial piece of code which creates kernel-threads. Kernel threads are processes managed by the kernel. user-threads are part of a process. If you have a single-threaded process, than the whole process  itself would be a user-thread. User-Threads make system-calls and this system-calls are served by a specific kernel-Thread which belongs to the calling user-threads. So for ervery user-thread which make a system call, a kernel-thread is created and after the kernel-thread has done its job, it gives control back to the user-thread and then the kernel-threas is destroyed."

Would this be ok?

Thank you!

Many greetings from Germany!

Comment: There are **a lot** of resources about terms "kernel threads" and "user threads". Also, there are many questions on Stack Overflow on this topic. Have you tried to read them before asking the question?

Comment: Actually yes, but i was not sure if i have understood it correctly...

Comment: The question "Would this be ok?" is **too broad**, as it requests resolution on an **unspecified criteria**: aside from checking whether every sentence is not false, we can check e.g. whether sentences are complete. Please, ask a **specific question** instead. For example, you could ask "Whether a kernel thread is created every time when a syscall is needed to be processed and destroyed afterwards?".

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that's a very good mental model for kernel vs user. I think it's useful to look at the implementation of these abstractions in order to fully understand them:

## What is a Kernel?

A kernel is basically just a piece of memory. It was privileged enough to be loaded before anything else, thereby allowing it to set the CPU's interrupt vectors.

Interrupts control everything, including I/O, timers, and virtual memory. That means that the kernel gets to decide how all that is handled.

A library is also just a piece of memory, and you can very well look at the kernel as the "system call library", among other things. But because the kernel represents the hardware, that piece of memory is shared among everyone.

## Kernel Mode vs User Mode

Kernel mode is the CPU's "natural" mode, with no restrictions (on x86 CPUS - "ring 0"). User mode (on x86 CPUs - "ring 3") is when the CPU is instructed to trigger an interrupt whenever certain instructions are used or whenever some memory locations are accessed. This allows the kernel to have the CPU execute specific kernel code when the user tries to access kernel memory or memory representing I/O ports or hardware memory such as the GPU's frame buffer.

## Processes and Threads

A process is also just a piece of memory, consisting of its own heap and the memory used by libraries, among which is the kernel.

A thread (= a unit of scheduling) is just a stack with an ID that the kernel knows of and tracks. That's the call stack that the CPU uses when the thread is running. User threads have 2 stacks: one for user mode and one for kernel mode - but they still have the same ID.

Because the kernel controls timers, it sets up a timer to go off e.g. every 1 ms. When the timer triggers ("timer interrupt"), the CPU runs the callback that the kernel set up for that interrupt, where the kernel can see that the current thread has been running for a while and decide to unschedule it and schedule another thread instead.

## Virtual Memory Context

By "virtual memory context" I mean all the memory that can be accessed by the CPU. This includes all the memory of the process - including the user-mode heap and memory of libraries, user-mode call stacks of all process threads, kernel-mode stack of all threads in the system, the kernel's heap memory, I/O ports, and hardware memory.

When an interrupt or a system call occur, the virtual memory context doesn't change, only a CPU flag is flipped (i.e. from ring 3 to ring 0) and the CPU is now back in its "natural" kernel mode where it can freely access kernel memory, I/O ports and hardware memory.

When a new process is created, what actually happens is that a new thread is created, and assigned a new virtual memory context. Therefore, every process starts as single-threaded. That thread can later ask the kernel via a system call to create more threads (= stacks) which share its virtual memory context (= process), or ask the kernel to create more threads, each with a new virtual memory context (= new processes).

## Kernel Threads

Like any other library, the kernel can have its own background threads for optimization purposes. When such a need arises (which can happen in the memory context of any process when servicing a system call), the kernel will create new threads and give them a special memory context, which is a context that only contains the kernel's memory, with no access to memory of any process.

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing up a few somewhat different concepts.

To follow from what you wrote, there is a **Kernel**, which is a piece of code that handles all internal operations of the Operating System. It does create kernel threads, but the Kernel threads are nothing special. They are just threads which run in **"Kernel-Mode"** and are not associated with any **"User-Mode"** process.

Now we have a concept which is lacking from your explanation and is the key to understand it better. Kernel-Mode (or sometimes called system mode), along with User-Mode make up CPU modes available to OS.

**Kernel-Mode** is a kind of trusted execution mode, which allows the code to access any memory and execute any instruction. It handles I/O and system interrupts.

**User-Mode** is a limited mode, which does not allow the executing code to access any memory address except those associated with the User-Mode process.

Also User-Mode cannot access I/O or those many OS related function (such as handle or process creation). For these operations, User-Mode code should call into Kernel-Mode, by a system call (as you have correctly mentioned).

A **system call** is a special CPU instruction which switches the CPU mode to Kernel-Mode and starts executing a special code provided by OS which dispatches different system calls. So, it means the work is NOT scheduled for a Kernel-Mode thread, instead the OS (kernel/trusted) code is executed in the context of the same User-Mode thread. The only thing that happens is that CPU mode changes to Kernel-Mode.

As for completing jobs in a **Kernel-thread**, I should say although in some cases, some operations (e.g. I/O) might be scheduled for a separate Kernel thread to complete, but the Kernel threads are not created and destroyed in the process of a system call.

Backed by:
10+ years of driver development experience

Also: 
http://www.linfo.org/kernel_mode.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/user-mode-and-kernel-mode

Comment: Thank you for your answer so far. So it's fair to say, that a Kernel-Thread is just a Process with the most privileges (Kernel-Mode) and they are wandering around in the OS waiting to handle a syscall? So they are capable of handling all kinds of syscalls and no Kernel-Thread is associated with a specific sys-call?

Comment: Yes and no. 

Yes, Kernel-threads are threads which operate only in Kernel-Mode, they are created by code running in Kernel-Mode (e.g. kernel and device drivers) to facilitate some operations asynchronously, such as pending I/O operations.

No, they are not related or correlated to sys-calls. Actually most of the processing which happens as the result of a sys-call is done in the context of the requesting thread, which is a User-Thread. In other words, the user-thread is running in Kernel-Mode and executing Kernel code.