# Does a kernel-level thread still have a process running with it?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, kernel

So if i understand correctly, a user-level thread has a thread control block and a process running the actual thread. That process which runs the thread is what is actually scheduled to run. That process is then what gives the OS access to the OS's resources.

In the case of kernel-level threads, is there still a process with process control block running along side it to provide access to the computers resources?

Comment: "Kernel-level thread" probably only has any meaning if you put it in the context of some particular operating system. E.g., Linux has something called "kernel threads" which are not associated with any process.

Comment: Re, "process running the actual thread." Probably not a good way to think about it. In a model of computing that has "threads," I would say that the threads do _all_ of the work.\* A process is just a bundle of resources (virtual memory, file handles, etc.) that are used by one or more threads.  [\* ignoring ISRs for simplicity's sake.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57160637/10678955