# Does kernel spawn some processes (not user process) that keep running in background?

Tags: process, operating-system, kernel

I'm learning the concepts of operating system. This is part I've learned: kernel is key piece of os that does lots of critical things such as memory management, job scheduling etc.

This is part what I'm thinking and get confused: to have os operating as expected, in a sense kernel needs to keep running, perhaps in the background, so it is always able to respond to different system calls and interrupts. In order to achieve this, I think of two completely different approaches:

1. kernel actually spawns some processes purely on its behalf, not user process, and keep them running in background (like daemon)? These background processes will handle housekeeping stuff without acknowledgement from user or user process. I call this approach as "kernel is running on its own"
2. There is no kernel process at all. Every process we can find in os are all user processes. Kernel is nothing but a library (piece of code, along with some key data structures like page tables etc) shared among all these user processes. In each process's address space, some portion of kernel will be loaded so that when any interrupt or system call occurs, mode is elevated to kernel mode. Pieces of kernel code loaded into user process's address space will be executed so that kernel can handle the event. When kernel does that, it is still in the context of current user process. In this approach, there exists only user processes, but kernel will periodically run within the context of each user process (but in a different mode).

This is a conceptual question that has confused me for a while. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, A library can have its own background threads.

Secondly, the answer is somewhere between these approaches.

Most Unix-like system are built on a [monolithic kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernel) (or hybrid one). That means the kernel contains all its background work in kernel threads in a single address space. I wrote in more details about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57235837/10678955).

On most Linux distributions, you can run

```
ps -ef | grep '\[.*\]'
```

And it will show you kernel threads.
But it will not show you "the kernel process", because `ps` basically only shows threads. Multithreaded processes will be seen via their main thread. But  the kernel doesn't have a main thread, it owns all the threads.

If you want to look at processes via the lens of address spaces rather than threads, there's not really a way to do it. However, address spaces are useless if no thread can access them, So you access the actual address space of a thread (if you have permission) via `/proc/<pid>/mem`. So if you used the above `ps` command and found a kernel thread, you can see its address space using this approach.
But you don't have to search - you can also access the kernel's address space via `/proc/kcore`.

You will see, however, that these kernel threads aren't, for the most part, core kernel functionality such as scheduling & virtual memory management. In most Unix kernels, these happen during a system call by the thread that made the system call while it's running in kernel mode.

Windows, on the other hand, is built on a [microkernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel). That means that the kernel launches other processes and delegates work to them.
On Windows, that microkernel's address space is represented by the ["System" service](https://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/process/system.html). The other processes - file systems, drivers etc., and other parts of what a monolithic kernel would comprise e.g. virtual memory management - might run in user mode or kernel mode, but still in a different address space than the microkernel.

You can get more details on how this works [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_of_Windows_NT).

Thirdly, just to be clear, that none of these concepts is to be confused with "system daemon", which are the regular userspace daemons that an OS needs in order to function, e.g. [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsyslog), [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), etc..

Those are generally created by the "init" process (PID 1 on Unix systems) e.g. systemd, however systemd itself is created by the kernel at boot time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is mostly no. The kernel doesn't spawn kernel mode processes. At boot, the kernel might start some executables but they run in user mode as a privileged user. For example, the Linux kernel will start systemd as the first user mode process as the root user. This process will read configuration files (written by your distribution's developers like Ubuntu) and start some other processes like the X Server for graphics and basic input (from keyboard, mouse, etc).

Your #1 is wrong and your #2 is also somewhat wrong. The kernel isn't a library. It is code loaded in the top half of the virtual address space. The bottom half of the VAS is very big (several tens of thousands of GB) so user mode processes can become very big as long as you have physical RAM or swap space to back the memory they require. The top half of the VAS is shared between processes. For the bottom half, every process has theoretical access to all of it.

The kernel is called on system call and on interrupt. It doesn't run all the time like a process. It simply is called when an interrupt or syscall occurs. To make it work with more active processes than there are processor cores, timers will be used. On x86-64, each core has one local APIC. The local APIC has a timer that you can program to throw an interrupt after some time. The kernel will thus give a time slice to each process, choose one process in the list and start the timer with its corresponding time slice. When the timer throws an interrupt, the kernel knows that the time slice of that process is over and that it might be time to let another process take its place on that core.